# Есть ли аналог cowsay, но выводящий кота?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Есть ли программа для linux аналогичная cowsay, но выводящая кота, вместо коровы?

Comment: почему бы в поисковике не поискать. Нашёл на первой странице поиска https://github.com/audy/catsay

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cowsay` из коробки может выводить не только собственно бурёнок, но и целый спектр других <strike>животных</strike> «коров» (от куриц до слонов и змей). Весь список можно получить от него самого:

```
$ cowsay -l
Cow files in /usr/share/cowsay/cows:
apt beavis.zen bong bud-frogs bunny calvin cheese cock cower daemon default
dragon dragon-and-cow duck elephant elephant-in-snake eyes flaming-sheep
ghostbusters gnu head-in hellokitty kiss koala kosh luke-koala mech-and-cow
milk moofasa moose mutilated pony pony-smaller ren sheep skeleton snowman
sodomized-sheep stegosaurus stimpy suse three-eyes turkey turtle tux
unipony unipony-smaller vader vader-koala www
```

Использовать соответствующих коров можно с помощью ключа `-f`:

```
$ cowsay -f elephant-in-snake "На самом деле я съела шляпу, а не слона, но ни кому не говорите."
 ___________________________________
/ На самом деле я съела шляпу, а не \
\ слона. Но ни кому не говорите.    /
 -----------------------------------
       \
        \  ....
          .    ........
          .            .
          .             .
    .......              .........
    ..............................
```

К несчастью авторы совершили ужасное упущение и не включили в базовую поставку ни одного кота. К счастью это легко исправить: надо лишь создать свою корову в форме кошки. По факту коровы представляют из себя perl-скрипты, хотя и довольно простые, но всё же стоит быть осторожным при их написании. Примеры можно найти в `/usr/share/cowsay/cows`. Тем? кто как и я не одарён мастерством ASCII-art'а, можно просто найти кота в гугле и подрисовал ему стрелочку прямой речи:

```
$ cat ~/tmp/cat.cow
## an ASCII cat found in google
$the_cow = <<"EOC"
  $thoughts
   $thoughts
   |\\_._/|
   |-o.o-|
   (  T  )
  .^`-^-'^.
  `.  ;  .'
  | | | | |
 ((_((|))_))
EOC
```

Результат:

```
$ cowsay -f ~/tmp/cat.cow "Кошки это хорошо."
 ___________________
< Кошки это хорошо. >
 -------------------
  \
   \
   |\_._/|
   |-o.o-|
   (  T  )
  .^`-^-'^.
  `.  ;  .'
  | | | | |
 ((_((|))_))
```

Дабы сделать <strike>кота</strike> корову доступной без указания полного пути можно положить его к остальным в `/usr/share/cowsay/cows` или добавить свой путь к нему в переменную `COWPATH`.

Замечания:

- Перед запуском скрипта устанавливаются специальные переменные, `$thoughts`, `$eyes` и `$tongue`, в которых хранятся изображения для мыслей, глаз и языка соответственно.
- в HEREDOC перла, как выше, бекслеши нужно дополнительно эскейпить.
- См. [`man cowsay`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cowsay)